# XML declaration of rotated text wants to take two lines

Tags: android, xml, textview

I have the following TextView which I want to display at the side of my screen:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewJobcardTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:rotation="270"
    android:text="@string/job_cards"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:textSize="@dimen/header_text" />
```

As declared, the text, consisting of the two words "job cards" is rotated, but wants to take up two lines. I assume this is because the rotation confuses the calculation of the layout height. When I add maxLines="1" the second word disappears, rather than forcing the text onto a single line. When I expand the layout_height to a numeric value, nothing happens. When I expand the width, the text disappears. I assume the latter is because the text is not visible outside the parent layout.
Is there a way to do this in XML? Do I need to do it programatically, first rotating, and then recalculating the layout height/width?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `\n` in between `job` and `cards`.

I.e., `job\ncards`.

Comment: I think the OP means he _doesn't_ want that to happen.

Comment: @MikeM. is correct, I want the string to appear as a single line. Sorry if that wasn't clear.